# R - Sampling blackjack cards

Tags: r, sampling

A five card charlie is where you draw five cards and don't go bust, i.e. the points from 5 cards is <= 21. I want to find the probability of a 5 card charlie by brute force - i.e. simulate a large number of "plays" and check if you go bust or not.

by using brute force using R. I'm assuming here that there are 4 decks as is common in Casinos, and I'm sampling 5 cards from these 4 decks, checking if they've won and if so counting it towards the probability. Googling states it should be around 1/50, i.e. 2%:

```
deck <- c(rep(1:9, 16), rep(10, 64))
n <- 0 
size <- 1:10e6

for (i in size){
  smpl <- sample(deck,5,replace = F)
  if (sum(smpl) <= 21){
    n <- n+1
  }
}

print(n/max(size) * 100)

[1] 5.98644
```

Note that "deck" here is the point system, i.e. we have 1:9 points for 4 suits, and 4 deck of cards hence need 1:9 16 times, and similarly Jack Queen King and Ten all count as ten but 4*4*4 possible cards.

Sample 5 cards without replacement, check if the sum is <= 21, and if so count it, then finally do this 10 million times and calculated the probability. However this gives 6% rather than 2%.

I have two questions:

1) How can I modify this so that I can sample 100 million or more plays?

2) Where am I going wrong with the 6% probability?

Comment: @Hack-R I thought the link explained it better than I would, but I have added an explanation.

Comment: @Hack-R Apologies - all removed!

Comment: Your code appears to assume that you reshuffle/reuse all 4 decks before you draw a hand. You could also use all of the cards available before re-shuffling and you would get a different result. You also could include other players who have a probability of using up cards you need and get an even different result. When you are comparing your 5% to the 2% you found online did you make sure you were comparing apples to apples?

Comment: @AdamSampson What do you mean by reshuffling/reuse? You're right I am assuming no players. All I'm assuming is we have 4 decks, and we are choosing at random within those decks

Comment: At a casino you can draw a hand, then reshuffle, then draw, then reshuffle...etc. Or, you can draw a hand and play, then draw another hand without reshuffling the deck, then draw another hand...etc. Most casinos will randomly draw several hands and then reshuffle before you reach the end of the deck. Rarely will you reshuffle every hand or draw the whole deck before reshuffling.

Comment: @AdamSampson Thanks - I guess I don't see what impact it would have. With my code, by using the sample function, I am reshuffling each time I get a card? i.e. each hand. Is that correct? How would not reshuffling look like, in terms of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is off here is the assumption that it should be 2%.

Your code said about 5%. I've adapted an [existing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183749/number-of-5-card-charlie-hands-in-blackjack) and it also says 5%:

```
deck       <- c(rep(1:9, 4), rep(10, 16))
result     <- combn(deck, 5, function(x) {sum(x) <= 21})

sum(result)/dim(result)
```

> ```
> [1] 0.05385693
> ```

Comment: Thanks - That method fails unfortunately if you have more than 5-Charlie, e.g. 6 as the number of combinations is ridiculously high. The example here is with only one deck also unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @user33484 I thought the question was for 5-card Charlie? this, combined with the earlier results, seems to prove the 2% number is just a faulty assumption

Answer (score 0):

For `k = 5, 6, 7` - card charlie you could try the following (to compute the probability with simulation) with `replicate`:

```
sapply(5:7, function(k) mean(replicate(n=10^6, 
                           sum(sample(c(rep(1:9, 4), rep(10, 16)), k, replace = F)) <= 21)))
#[1] 0.053943 0.008525 0.000890
```

Here is how the probability decreases with k (for k-card charlie)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(card, prob), 
      data=data.frame(card=2:7, prob=sapply(2:7, function(x) mean(replicate(n=10^6, sum(sample(c(rep(1:9, 4), rep(10, 16)),x,replace = F)) <= 21))))) + 
      geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]